# System formatted after editing Network Interfaces

Tags: 14.04, server, format

So, something strange happened to me today.

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 and had to replace a few certificates. After that, I edited my /etc/network/interface file to change the IP and then tried ifdown -a && ifup -a.

When I ran the command, as root user, obviously, the response was "cannot access file /etc/network/interface".

I rebooted the server using the "reboot" command and after the start up, I got a "non system disk or disk error" message. My entire machine, OS included, was deleted!

What happened???

Comment: Hard to know from what you posted but sounds like hardware failure.

Comment: Seemed fine after I reinstalled everything...?

Comment: Well if the hard drive is failing it can behave this way too. WE need to see logs, error messages, check your hard drive for errors, etc ...

Comment: Also, when I got that error, I did manage to access the file using nano. Only after the reboot was everything deleted.

Comment: Will the syslog show anything if I had to reinstall?

Comment: possible . You have to look at logs and see what if anything they show. Also use smartmontools to check your disk for errors.